# Fit string to terminal width, but take wide characters like TAB into account

Tags: string, python-3.x, truncate

Do you have an idea how to trim strings down to a specific length (i.e. terminal width), but with taking special "wide" characters like tabs into account?

I have these lines, `line` is a bytes string and `max_width` is evaluated to 132:

```py
max_width = shutil.get_terminal_size().columns
output = "{:>6d}: {}".format(n, line.decode(codec, "replace")).rstrip("\n")
print(output[:max_width])
print(len(output[:max_width]))
```

And an example output would be this:

```
    23: ��G&S��.��+��HL=`����W9�yi��l�����p����:��d*p��i�6L�h<��
v�I��S�� �u�`:%��#                                               ��/����TAE����{�(y�Ij��B����33o3
132
```

So Python3 thinks it's only 132 chars, but the terminal (`gnome-terminal` on Ubuntu 15.10) interprets it to 293 chars, according to `wc`.

How can I truncate the line correctly, so that it fits into one terminal row?

Comment: The number of spaces to use for a TAB character is completely up to the terminal / application  / user. This is why you don't use tabs for alignment. Convert them to spaces.

Comment: Could I simply replace all "wide" characters with a fixed number of spaces myself before truncating the string? What other characters than TAB would I have to take care of then? (e.g. line-feed or carriage-return or or whatever) What would be the simplest way to handle them all at once?

Answer (score 0):

I do now re-construct each string and simply omit all non-printable characters.
This is probably not the fastest method, but it works.

```
output = line.decode(codec, "replace")
if max_width:
    output = "".join(c for c in output if c.isprintable())
    print(output[:max_width])
else:
    print(output)
```